# Reading different types of variables from a text file in java

Tags: java

My file is formatted like this

```
111,name,111`
```

so the format is (int,string,int) with "," as the delimiter
now all I need to do is to read the file and assign them to different variables

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream movies = new FileInputStream("res\\test.txt");
        try (Scanner inFile = new Scanner(movies)) {
            inFile.useDelimiter(",");
            while (inFile.hasNext()) {
                int i1 = inFile.nextInt();
                String i2 = inFile.next();
                int i3 = inFile.nextInt();    
            }
        }
    }
```

when I use " " space as delimiter it works but I can't make it work with comma as the delimiter

Comment: You could read one like at a time as a string, then split the line you have read using `string.split(_<useDelimiterStringHere>_)`. This should give you a String array. The values would still be string till this point. Then you can parse elements of this String array by position and handle any conversion errors there.  Hope this helps.

Comment: The format of the file is a .txt, so the file format is actually String,String,String when reading this is it a requirement to covert the String value of 111 to an int?